# Team Explorer always shows .SLN file as "changed" in memory when it isn't

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, team-explorer

Visual Studio (2019) Team Explorer always shows my VS solution file (the .SLN file) for one project as being changed in memory when I have that solution open.  Even after a completely clean pull of the code.

[image]

My problem is nearly identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887016/teamexplorer-with-git-in-visualstudio-2017-claims-solution-file-has-changed-whi).   Except in my case, there is no incomplete line in the solution file that might be the cause.  At least nothing that I can see.

And like the guy in the other post, if I try to stage the "changed" solution file, I get the following output:

```
File not staged because it is modified in memory but not saved to disk
```

I go to File >> Save All, nothing changes.  If I close the solution, I am not prompted to save any changes to the solution file.  And the next time I open it up, it's just as it was again.

If make some change, like, say, add a file to the "Solution" items, then I can save everything check in and it disappears from the list of changed files.  But the next time I open the solution, it's back to "changed".

Below is my solution file which otherwise works perfectly.  Can anyone spot anything that might be causing this?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.28803.156
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxcore", "gxcore\gxcore_v16.vcxproj", "{15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxanalysis", "gxanalysis\gxanalysis_v16.vcxproj", "{B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxcoretests", "gxcoretests\gxcoretests_v16.vcxproj", "{FF9FE855-662B-4B14-A336-042983CE8227}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6} = {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
        {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1} = {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxdevice", "gxdevice\gxdevice_v16.vcxproj", "{3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxapple", "gxapple\gxapple_v16.vcxproj", "{6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6} = {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxinternal", "gxinternal\gxinternal_v16.vcxproj", "{7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6} = {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxversion", "gxversion\gxversion_v16.vcxproj", "{C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxanalysistests", "gxanalysistests\gxanalysistests_v16.vcxproj", "{F1990AA9-201D-415B-846E-C884E5C79F2C}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6} = {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}
        {6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7} = {6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7}
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
        {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1} = {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}
        {7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A} = {7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxlicense", "gxlicense\gxlicense_v16.vcxproj", "{060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "include", "include\include_v16.vcxitems", "{73CAFD64-AA61-4F1C-ACB8-490D0CC84DDB}"
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "gxhostid", "gxhostid\gxhostid_v16.vcxproj", "{CF521884-947A-4E1B-8B1C-A6D7BA103F54}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}") = "GxCore.Sdk", "corecli\corecli_v16.vcxproj", "{1327C0A1-442E-4CEA-9E2C-B0883754EC41}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6} = {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967} = {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200} = {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C} = {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{776DC2AC-6C30-4400-AD6C-62B3C23390E9}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .gitignore = .gitignore
        deploy.bat = deploy.bat
        deploy_internal.bat = deploy_internal.bat
        get3rdparty.bat = get3rdparty.bat
        get3rdpartyimpl.bat = get3rdpartyimpl.bat
        sdk-windows-build.yml = sdk-windows-build.yml
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {15E8787B-DC6C-40AB-A5C7-7C9708566200}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {B9233615-52F9-440C-80FD-8DAF210BCCE6}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {FF9FE855-662B-4B14-A336-042983CE8227}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {FF9FE855-662B-4B14-A336-042983CE8227}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {FF9FE855-662B-4B14-A336-042983CE8227}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {FF9FE855-662B-4B14-A336-042983CE8227}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {3214A3C3-E86E-4096-8733-7B29573FF3D1}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {6B38F03E-DC5C-4467-A5E0-70355A0D07A7}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {7056E8E7-5CDD-4B99-97EA-E520BB530A9A}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {C8CB862D-1109-459B-8C79-E07DAA3DD967}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {F1990AA9-201D-415B-846E-C884E5C79F2C}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {F1990AA9-201D-415B-846E-C884E5C79F2C}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {F1990AA9-201D-415B-846E-C884E5C79F2C}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {F1990AA9-201D-415B-846E-C884E5C79F2C}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {060C0384-58CE-439D-B366-D85581F2515C}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {CF521884-947A-4E1B-8B1C-A6D7BA103F54}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {CF521884-947A-4E1B-8B1C-A6D7BA103F54}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {CF521884-947A-4E1B-8B1C-A6D7BA103F54}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {CF521884-947A-4E1B-8B1C-A6D7BA103F54}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
        {1327C0A1-442E-4CEA-9E2C-B0883754EC41}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|x64
        {1327C0A1-442E-4CEA-9E2C-B0883754EC41}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|x64
        {1327C0A1-442E-4CEA-9E2C-B0883754EC41}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|x64
        {1327C0A1-442E-4CEA-9E2C-B0883754EC41}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|x64
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {C6B1295C-E2FB-4B3D-BC15-BD5174DCE2BC}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```